# Is it possible to use the PayPal API to connect to different users' accounts to pay (credit) them with funds?

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, account

I can't really talk much about the what we're trying to build but we want it to have a somewhat complicated (or at last not very simple) payment component. So here's the details of that payment component.

In the simplest terms, this is system where we have two types of users who can sign up for an account.

The first type of user (let's call them "seller" as per PayPal-speak), uses our platform to offer a specific type of service, find people requiring that type of service and perform that specific service which generates us (the owners of the service) money because the sellers use use our platform (website, app, listings, etc.) to be found.

The second type of user (let's call them buyers) uses our platform to find the very specific type of service being offered by sellers. They connect with individual sellers, the sellers perform their service but in the end they must pay us the cost of the service of the seller plus a percentage that we take on sales.

So ideally in a single transaction, we take payments from a buyer, the recipient of service performed by a seller via Paypal and those payments go to our (master) PayPal account. Next, we take our cut, and then send payment (or credit) the PayPal account of the seller with the money they earned.

So to accomplish this I'm wondering:

- Can PayPal do this?
- If so, what type of type of PayPal account(s) would we need to arrange this as the people building this service?
- Given that PayPal has a lot of APIs which API(s) are necessary to do this?
- Is PayPal the best payment service to use for this?
- If PayPal can't do this which payment service could ? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You connect to your *own* account to pay other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through PayPal using adaptive payments. Here is a link to more information on adaptive payments and what is needed to set it up. You would need a business account and the recipients, or your "sellers", would also need PayPal accounts.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/